# Each time I down load, Android Studio Requesting if I want to unistall the existing application?

Tags: android

I keep getting the same message each time I try to download my app to my tablet.  I have gone to my tablet and deleted every app that I have ever built but still get the same error?

```
Installation failed with message Invalid File: 
/home/gary/AndroidStudioProjects/wifi-direct-demo-master1/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk. 

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version 
of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.  
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!  
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

I was working on my laptop and have since switched to a company supplied computer, so the /home/gary is my laptop and /home/jpogge is the company computer.

Comment: Delete the `.idea` folder in the project?

Answer (score 0):

You might have the app still installed for other users. You can't see them among your apps but if you go to Settings/Apps/All, they are at the bottom listed as 'Not installed'. Remove them for all users.

Alternatively, I've also found that a clean build solves the problem; clean project -> rebuild from build menu.